# vim: jump to buffer that contains /string/

Tags: vim

I normally have quite a few buffers opened, which I navigate using combination of Bufexplorer and FuzzyFinder. Finding the right buffer still involves going through file names. But often, it could be much easier to say something like 'jump to buffer that contains "wip"'. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a small function I put inside my .vimrc:

```
function! s:GrepOpenBuffers(search, jump)
    call setqflist([])
    let cur = getpos('.')
    silent! exe 'bufdo vimgrepadd /' . a:search . '/ %'
    let matches = len(getqflist())
    if a:jump && matches > 0
        sil! cfirst
    else
        call setpos('.', cur)
    endif
    echo 'BufGrep:' ((matches) ? matches : 'No') 'matches found'
endfunction
com! -nargs=1 -bang BufGrep call <SID>GrepOpenBuffers('<args>', <bang>0)
```

You could use something like the above to grep for a search term in all opened buffers.

Comment: Very cool! If only it could also jump to the first match... May be?

Comment: @artemave to jump to the first match you would have to use `:BufGrep! search_term`

Answer (score 2):

Check out buffer grep: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2545

Comment: Good point! Actually I have EasyGrep installed that can also search buffers... But! All the *grep plugins I've come across open results in quickfix window. What I'd ideally want instead is instant jump through to (say, first) match. Like 'gf' or tags'.